# I want to use vlfeat for recognizing one class

Tags: matlab, svm, object-recognition, vlfeat

I'm trying to use the vlfeat (matlab) example caltech101 for just one class but it doesn't seem to work. If I only feed one class to the svm trainer the results are 50/50. Should I take something else into account or is it that the one class svm objective function is not implemented in vlfeat and it just won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one-class SVM is a **different** algorithm, not jus "one class svm kernel" - you are confusing two things here.

Second, vlfeat supports just a simple binary SVM ( http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_svmtrain.html ) so the answer is "you should use other library" - original libsvm have Matlab bindings and supports (among others) one-class SVM.